# Flux maps (?) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, mapping, theme

How this kind of map that I think is called "Flux map" can be performed in QGIS?

[image]

I'd like to implement it in a time model of wind streams.

Comment: I'm disturbed that this question was closed so abruptly. What exactly does the poster need to add or clarify that is missing in the question? I did a quick internet search on the topic and nothing turned up. I've seen this kind of flux map elsewhere (windy.com, for example), and I think it would be important to see how this might be accomplished within QGIS.

Comment: I agree about this. Furthermore, I think this kind of performance could have a wide field of applications.